Line Of Sight in javascript DOM game
I am creating a 2D game in javascript using pure DOM, on my computer and on my cell phone WebGL or OpenGL do not work. 
How can I create Lights and shadows effects using Line Of Sight, for example, I want to create a javascript class that adds the tag  a circular object called "light", and I want this light to throw rays in all directions from the center of the light, what if the light touches an object of the sprite class it projects a shadow of the object

For the "rays in all directions" algorithm, you may want to check out the Red Blob Games article explaining 2D visibility. How that gets implemented for your game world depends on what kinds of obstacles you have and how they're positioned. To get help with that, show us a sample of your code / DOM and a preview of that you want the result to look like.

When you write that you are using "pure dom", then that means you are not even using canvas? This is not going to be easy.
